# SignInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync doesn't set all claims

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

In a ASP.NET Core 7 application have extended `IdentityUser` like this:

```cs
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
  public string? FirstName { get; set; }
  public string? LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I created  a DB conext:

```cs
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
{
  public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
    : base(options)
  {
  }
}
```

I'm configuring my host to use it:

```cs
services
  .AddDefaultIdentity<AppUser>(
    options
      => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true
  )
  .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

When debugging the running application, `Request.User` is of type `ClaimsPrincipal`
which holds the Claims including `FirstName` and `LastName` as expected.

However, when I'm using `UserManager<AppUser>` and `SignInManager<AppUser>` to create a `ClaimsPrincipal`, the claims are missing (not all Claims are missing, though).

This is how I'm creating the `ClaimsPrincipal` within a test.

`_host` is using the exact same configuration as the running application does.

```cs
var userManager =
  _host.Services.GetService<UserManager<AppUser>>();

var appUser = userManager
  .Users
  .FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == user.Sub);

var signInManager =
  _host.Services.GetService<SignInManager<AppUser>>();

_claimsPrincipal = await signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(appUser);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using an `IClaimsTransformation` which adds the missing claims.

`IClaimsTransformation`s are only run on actual authentication which is not the case in my test.